# Element-wise logical auto-combination of pandas boolean series

Tags: python, pandas, series, elementwise-operations, logical-and

```
s = pandas.Series([True,False,True,True,False])
len(s)==5
```

while `len(s[:-1]) == len(s[1:]) = 4`,

the element-wise AND combination `len(s[1:] & s[:-1]) = 5`,

even `len(s[1:].copy() & s[:-1].copy()) = 5`

*environment is python3.6 on Jupyter, pandas 0.21.0*

Answer (score 0):

Its because element-wise logical `&` operation is strictly based on indexing.
And the combination of two mis-indexed series gives `None`, which is treated as `False`.
The combination is full-join, so final length is `len(s) == len(s[1:] & s[:-1]) = 5`.